# JPA - Passing parameter for customizing lazy loading of foreign key constraints

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I don't know how to name this problem correctly. I have some entities which are connected to each other via foreign key constraints (ManyToOne and OneToMany). All those entities have an inherited table where meta data like "is deleted" are stored. Inheritance is done by `InheritanceType.JOINED`. All foreign key constraints are lazy loaded.

Now, when I want to query *deleted* entities only, I also want subsequent accesses to an entity's foreign key constraint to return only deleted entries. Is it possible to pass a parameter `deletedOnly` to the query, so that even all foreign key constraints are affected when the developer accesses them by lazy loading?

Reason for this is a management platform where the customer can manage its entities. Deletion of entities is done via `delete` flag. Sometimes deleted entities need to be restored. So there is need for a view showing only non-deleted entities and a view showing deleted entities. This platform also shows foreign key constraints with a variable depth level, those may also contain entities which have been deleted.

If this is possible, I see one problem here. What if in the same session a developer wants to retrieve deleted entities only, but in a further processing in the application he needs to retrieve non-deleted entities, too? For constraints, if `PersistenceBag` is initialized once the query won't be done again.

Example code:

Entity **Shop** *1:n* Entity **Area**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop extends model.Entity {
    private String name;

    private Collection<Area> areas = new ArrayList<Area>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Collection<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "shop_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_area")
public class Area extends model.Entity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Shop shop;
    private Collection<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    public Shop getShop() {
        return shop;
    }

    public void setShop(Shop shop) {
        this.shop = shop;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "area", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Target> getTargets() {
        return targets;
    }

    public void setTargets(Collection<Target> targets) {
        this.targets = targets;
    }

}
```

The super entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the code for models and EF query ?

Comment: @Sampath I added sample code in the question. The query might just be a `EntityManager#find` or any other non-native query.

Comment: can you tell me why you cannot just retrieve the `deleted` and `non deleted` items by using the `flag` to show ? what is the problem there ?